# Docker containers can't talk to subnets but the docker host can, how do I find where the packets are being dropped?

Tags: networking, iptables, docker, openvpn, ipv6

We have a setup where we have a docker container which needs to talk to devices on a VPN (openvpn) over ipv6. This is done by constructing a bridge between the docker networks and the tap0 interface on the host.

The end devices push a message up to the docker container and expect to receive an acknowledgement message back. These are on different subnets, however, with the container and host sitting in the `bbbb::/64` subnet and the devices sitting on the `abcd::/64` (for the sake of illustration). There is a gateway sitting on `bbbb::abcd:2` which routes traffic from one subnet to the other, and the docker host has a gateway configuration for this.

To be clear:

```
bbbb::4001 <--> bbbb::2105 <--> bbbb::abcd:2 <--> abcd::/64
```

Where `bbbb::4001` is the address of the container; `bbbb::2105` is the address of the host; `bbbb::abcd2` is the address of the gateway device; `abcd::/64` is the subnet on which the end devices sit.

Using `tshark` on the host and the gateway, we observe the following:

1. The host can talk directly to end devices on the abcd subnet (checked with traceroute, could see packets on the host and the gateway);
2. The docker container can talk to the gateway (checked with ping, could see packets on the host and the gateway);
3. the docker container *could not* talk directly to end devices on the abcd subnet: we could see the packets on the host, in the same way as we saw them for the host's communication, but we did not see anything arrive on the gateway.

We have tried modifying `iptables` rules to allow forwarded packets (e.g. setting the default policy of the `FORWARD` chain to `ACCEPT`) but to no avail.

We're unclear where to look with this problem, because it seems that packets from the docker container destined for the subnet on which it does not sit get dropped *somewhere* on the host, OR perhaps get sent to the wrong place, but we do see them on the host's `br0` interface, they just never arrive at the gateway. When the docker container tries to talk to things on the same subnet as it, then it works.

Where do I start looking for this?

Comment: Maybe a routing problem? What is the output of `ip -6 route get abcd::0` (or some other specific address on that network) when run inside the container? Do you have any rules in the `FORWARD` table that might be limiting things despite the default policy?

Answer (score 3):

The problem was to do with docker's networking. We had a docker network setup to use a network bridge to connect to the VPN. That bridge was setup (via `/etc/network/interfaces.d/br0.cfg`) with a gateway address `bbbb::2105`, and the docker network was created after the bridge interface. When the docker network was created, the gateway address wasn't specified, and docker defaulted to using `bbbb::1` as the gateway address, which it forced `br0` to use. That address is the same address as the VPN server. The result was that packets weren't actually being dropped on the host, but instead forwarded to the VPN server's `tap` interface, and the VPN server didn't have the routing tables setup such that it knew what to do with those packets, so they effectively were blackholed once they reached the VPN server.

This was made clear by using tshark to monitor the VPN server's `tap` interface, as well as the `tap` interfaces on the gateways and the docker host machine. We then tried to ping an end device from inside the docker container, and we saw packets on the docker host and the VPN server, but not on the gateways. If we tried the same thing on the docker host, we saw packets on the docker host and the gateways but not on the VPN server, thus demonstrating that the docker containers were configured to send traffic to the VPN server rather than to the host networking interfaces.

The problem was fixed by introducing the `--gateway` option into the creation of the docker network.

The unresolved part of this is *why* this suddenly started behaving this way, given that the setup has worked since 2016 and randomly stopped working one day in June 2022.